Unable to install mediapipe on Windows
I tried to install mediapipe through CMD with python under windows but it doesn't work.
I tried various solutions. I don't know if it's me doing it wrong or I'm missing something. Whatever I do it always gives me this error message.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000018F42976130>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Une tentative d’accès à un socket de manière interdite par ses autorisations d’accès a été tentée')': /simple/mediapipe/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000018F429765B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Une tentative d’accès à un socket de manière interdite par ses autorisations d’accès a été tentée')': /simple/mediapipe/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000018F42976160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Une tentative d’accès à un socket de manière interdite par ses autorisations d’accès a été tentée')': /simple/mediapipe/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000018F42976D90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Une tentative d’accès à un socket de manière interdite par ses autorisations d’accès a été tentée')': /simple/mediapipe/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000018F429A4100>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] Une tentative d’accès à un socket de manière interdite par ses autorisations d’accès a été tentée')': /simple/mediapipe/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe

How do I do to resolve this?

Can you share the command you ran that resulted in this error?

yes it is
pip install mediapipe

Make sure that your internet connection is stable and you are not behind a restrictive network.if it still doesn't work then try running the installation command with administrative privileges or what you can do is also disable any firewall or antivirus that might be blocking the connection. Additionally you can manually download the library from the official source and install it using pip.

thank you
i forget that i use firewall to restriction connexion for update windows
thank you very much
that work
